# VISUAL BASIC - How do you set a listbox datasource to null

Tags: vb.net, null, listbox, datasource

I have a listbox where I am using this line of code to set the data source:

```
ListBox2.DataSource = TextBox2.Text.Select(Function(c) c).ToList()
```

after this, I am selecting the first item, reading it, and removing it. But when I try to remove an item it says

> Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.

So I did some reading and it looks like I need to set the datasource to `null`, but I cannot find how to do this in VB.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: How do you remove it?

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you do not need to set the `DataSource` to null. If you did then you would simply assign `Nothing`, like you do with any other variable or property, but that's not what you need to do. If you want to remove that item then you need to remove it from the data source. That's the point: if the control is bound then you don't modify the data in the control but rather in the data source.

The thing is, the control will not automatically update when you do that because it doesn't know that the data source has changed.  What you should do is bind your `List` to a `BindingSource` and bind that to the `ListBox`.  You can add the `BindingSource` in the designer.

```
BindingSource1.DataSource = TextBox2.Text.ToList()
ListBox2.DataSource = BindingSource1
```

You can then call `Remove`, `RemoveAt` or `RemoveCurrent` on the `BindingSource` to remove an item.  You can also call `ResetBindings` on the `BindingSource` to refresh the control if needs be.

Notice that I have also removed the redundant `Select` call from your code.  The `Text` property is type `String` and `String` already implements `IEnumerable(Of Char)` so there's no need for a `Select` call unless you want something other than the `Chars` themselves.